# Dependency Inversion in OOP (JS)

Tags: javascript, oop, jestjs

I am writing my first project that uses OOP in its design. It is basically a ship UI that travels and docks at different ports within an Itinerary. So I have created 3 classes (Ship, Port, and Itinerary) and basically injected the ports within the Itinerary as a list (array) and then injected that Itinerary within ship. With methods I have created such as SetSail() and dock() I am able to move my ship and make sure it docks at different ports. However, I have seen to hit a wall.

In a nutshell, in my Port class, I have created addShip() and removeShip() methods which I inject in my Ship class. The problem is when I try to use these add and removeShip methods in the Ship classes constructor, my unit test(written with Jest) points out a **typeError**: indicating that
**this.currentPort.addShip(this) is not a function.** But when I use these add and remove ship methods, within the methods I have created in the Ship class, it seems to work. Here is the code for the Ship class below;

```
class Ship{
    constructor(itinerary){
        this.itinerary = itinerary;
        this.currentPort = itinerary.ports[0];
        this.previousPort = null;
        this.currentPort.addShip(this);
        
        
    }

    setSail(){
        const itinerary = this.itinerary;
        const currentPortIndex = itinerary.ports.indexOf(this.currentPort);
      
        if (currentPortIndex === (itinerary.ports.length - 1)) {
          throw new Error('End of itinerary reached');
        }
      
        this.previousPort = this.currentPort;
        this.currentPort.removeShip(this);
        this.currentPort = null;
    }

    dock(){
        const itinerary = this.itinerary;
        const previousPortIndex = itinerary.ports.indexOf(this.previousPort);
        this.currentPort = itinerary.ports[previousPortIndex + 1];
        this.currentPort.addShip(this)
    }


}
```

Here is the code below for Port class

```
class Port {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
        this.ships = [];
        
    }

    addShip(ship){
        if(ship){
            this.ships.push(ship)
        }
    }

    removeShip(ship){
        if(ship){
            this.ships.pop(ship)
        }   
    }
}
```

I was expecting to addSHip method to work in the main Ship constructor, I have already managed to made them work in the methods inside the Ship class

Here is the Unit test that's pointing out the error;

```
describe("Ship", () => {
it('can be instantiated', () => {
    const port = new Port ('Dover');
    const itinerary = new Itinerary([[port]])
    const ship = new Ship(itinerary)
    expect(ship).toBeInstanceOf(Object)
})
```

Here is the Itinerary class that I have made;

```
class Itinerary{
constructor(ports){

    this.ports = ports;
    
}
```

}

Any help that will get me a pass on this instantiation test will be greatly appreciated. It's my first time writing OOP and testing it out with the Jest framework proved to be tricky

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add your `Itinerary` as well in the question.

Comment: While creating an `Itinerary`, you are passing an array inside an array (2d-array) `[[port]]`. But it should be just ar array or ports, meaning `const itinerary = new Itinerary([port])`.